# Cant hide delete/cancel button from jqgrid delete confirmation dialog box

Tags: angularjs

When I click on delete icon from jqgrid confirmation box appears and again when I click on delete button same popup with error message come. Now I want to modify jqgrid delete confirmation box when it appears second time, in that how can I disable Delete and Cancel button when dialog box popup???

Comment: You can set a flag to true when you click it for the first time and disable the button the next time based on this value. But this will fail if you reload the page.